# What to do with questions where repair/replacement is obviously the only answer?

Tags: discussion, questions, close-reasons

Every once in a while I see a question along the lines of:

> My iPhone got run over by a train, then my friend threw the pieces in a thermite fire, and the ashes were accidentally encased in concrete then shot directly into the sun. What do I do?? Help!!!

Where the immediately obvious only answer is "So... go buy a new one" or (not in the case of the above example, of course) "Well I guess you better take it to a repair center". I can't imagine what kind of results an asker would expect by asking such a question online, other than sympathy.

What is the standard practice around here for questions like this? Ignore them? Down vote? Flag / close (what reason)? Comment? Answer? I don't spend a lot of time on this site and I'm not sure how you guys like to treat these types of questions, or if they're even a problem. To me, it doesn't seem like they belong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flag to close would be my preference for dealing with these types of questions. For a reason you can say, "Unclear what you're asking" because, really, what *are* they asking for here? A repair center? Condolences? A mocking?

Comment: I try to resist the mocking, though sometimes it does slip through my usually resilient 'politeness filter'  ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin The temptation can be great and thankfully there's a delete button for comments when we lose perspective or are too frustrated to self-restrain.

Comment: @bmike - you may need to apply a late filter to this. Mea culpa, but while the answer survives, there may be hope for mankind. ;-)  http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/186211/can-i-actually-spray-paint-my-apple-watch-sport-gold/186326#186326

Comment: @Tetsujin oh god, that was just so...poetic. Have an up vote!

Answer (score 3):

I'm with Ian - down vote and then vote to close questions that are looking for an off-site resource without documenting the proper research the site asks for:

- Consider helping us help you. Take a pass at editing this after you've read the [help guide](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to be specific and show how your research didn't help you solve this dilemma.
- "Questions asking to [recommend or find a Mac, book, tool, tutorial or other off-site resource](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/) are off-topic for Ask Different as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, edit this question to [describe the problem and what research has been done](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) so far to solve it." – bmike

Also - keep in mind that **"they don't belong"** should always be enforced ruthlessly only on questions that don't clearly demonstrate some effort to be useful. We want to **include everyone**, even if they are struggling to learn the ropes - so ***be gracious and helpful to people, critical and clear about specific posts*** when you can call out specifically what's wrong with them and link to resources anyone can use to fix the poor posts.